# For loop variable having NULL value

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have this variable declaration

```
counter INTEGER := 0;        /* loop counter */
```

And then there is for loop like

```
FOR counter IN 1 .. CEIL(records / batch)
LOOP
```

No sooner the execution point comes here it throws execption.

```
ORA-01086: savepoint 'SP1' never established in this session or is invalid
ORA-06512: at "MALI521.PRVSAPUPD", line 421
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at line 8
```

Now the *SP1* savepoint is established in the for loop. The code is failing the moment it comes at for loop, since the counter variable there has *NULL* value.

Any idea?

PLEASE DELETE IT. I FIGURED IT OUT.

Comment: x.509 don't have this question deleted. Please post your own answer. I'm sure others will find it helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure `counter` is the problem?  what are the value of `records`  and `batch`

Comment: Are you saying this is caused by a division by zero or something? (Looking at a similar problem and stumbled on this question but there's not really much content.)

Comment: That was one option.  My other thought was `records` or `batch` were set to null, and anything divided by `null` would return `null`.

Comment: I encountered the same problem. Yes, if the records or batch is null, it will throw ORA-06512 error at the for statement line.